# Slide up hidden divs with absolute top

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm trying to show hidden div on hover from the bottom of the visible div. The hidden div should be with absolute top position reaching the top of the container. The problem is that hidden div is cutting the content on hover. Any suggestions how to prevent it?

Here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/emilium/rw5hz0cr/3/

```
var mh = $(".list-item").outerHeight();
$('.long-view').parent().css({position: 'relative', height: mh + 'px'});
$(".list-item").hover(function () {
  $(this).find(".long-view").css({
    visibility: "visible",
    top: mh + 'px',
    height: 0 + 'px',
    z: 100
  }).stop().animate({
    top: 0,
    height: mh,
   }, 1000);

}).mouseleave(function () {
$(this).find(".long-view").css({
    visibility: "hidden"
}).clearQueue().animate({
    height: "toggle"
}, 1500);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using overflow ? http://jsfiddle.net/rw5hz0cr/5/

```
.long-view {
    visibility: hidden;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top: 10px solid #E8E7E5;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 200px;
    background: yellow;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

**UPDATE**

The growing version : http://jsfiddle.net/rw5hz0cr/6/

**UPDATE**

http://jsfiddle.net/rw5hz0cr/7/

Comment: It's a nice solution, but it should be visible without any scrolling. :/

Comment: Then you will have to make the div longer. I edited my answer.

Comment: Awesome. This is just what I wanted to manage. It seems on the second hover is disappearing, is it from clearQueue()?

Comment: It is because your out animation reset the height to 0 so the next time the div can't grow because the height is not correct. I'll check if i can do something

Comment: Cool! Your latest update is working like a charm. And clearQueue() is removed! Great thanks. Should play more with data attributes.